# zsh - sh: node: command not found

Tags: node.js, zshrc

I am using `zsh` and I already installed `node`. In my `terminal`, when I key in:

```
$ node -v
```

I will get `v12.14.1`, that means my macbook already have `node` installed.

but when I do:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I got:

> ... env: node: No such file or directory ... sh: node: command not
>   found ...

I googled a bit and was advise to add this line to `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

but still not working.

another suggestion:

```
source /Users/xuanxi2020/.bash_profile
```

too, not working. Any other way to fix this?

Comment: Certainly not sourcing .bash_profile but .sourcing .zshrc instead if using zsh. Tried that? Also check which node is being used "which node" perhaps it came from a weird place

Comment: hmm, I am confuse now. when I `echo $0`, it tell me `-bash`.  But when I start terminal, it have this message: `The default interactive shell is now zsh.`. so which is which?

Comment: I would suggest install iTerm2 too, then you won't have these which is which issues. Perhaps follow https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/bash-to-zsh/#%F0%9F%92%BB